# Is there an equivalent to a linear model that uses the median as central descriptor for categories?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, median

Since the median is often a better central descriptor of skewed distributions, I'd like to know if there is an equivalent method to a linear model for explaining variability of one variable through a qualitative variable, that uses the median as coefficient for categories instead of the mean ?

(Kind of like the Kruskal-Wallis test is the equivalent of the ANOVA for the median)

Comment: You mean like quantile regression?

Comment: Oh. I was not introduced this entire field of regression in my studies. This seems to fit my description ! Thanks for pointing it out, I'll see what I can do with it. I'm surprised I didn't find (or maybe notice) it when I looked for stuff like "median linear model" and such

Comment: Well my number 1 google result for "median linear model" is quantile regression on wikipedia. The method also goes by the name "least absolute deviation"